# send multiple images from java server to android client

Tags: java, android, sockets

I need a server program in Java to be blocked until it receives a connection from a client android (froyo 2.2). When you unlock the Java server, send him pictures (more than one) and android client will receive and store on SD card.

The problem comes when the client side will try to get bitmap, which is locked and the program is not responding.

Get stuck at this point on Android code.
Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(in);

Server code (Java)

```
server= new ServerSocket(port);

while(true){
try{
    System.out.println("Wait for connect...");
    conex = server.accept();

    // The number of images to be sent.
    dataOutputStream = new DataOutputStream(conex.getOutputStream());
    dataOutputStream.writeInt(Path().list().length);
    dataOutputStream.flush();

    do{
        // Send the images
        if( j <= Path().list().length){
        image = (BufferedImage) ImageIO.read(new File(Path(),"img"+j+".jpg"));

        if (image != null) {
            try{
               System.out.println("Sending img "+"img"+j+".jpg...");
               OutputStream out = conex.getOutputStream();
               ImageIO.write(image, "JPEG", out);
               System.out.println("Image"+"img"+j+".jpg send correctly");
              out.flush();
              j++;
            } catch (IOException excepcionES ) {
              System.out.println( "Can't write object" );
            }
        } else {
            System.out.println("Can't read image...");
        }
       }

    // Wait until client store the image and cofirm that.
    System.out.println("Wait client confirmation...");
    dataInputStream = new DataInputStream(conex.getInputStream());
    modo = dataInputStream.readUTF();
    System.out.println("Receive from client: "+modo);

    }while(modo.equals("OK"));

} catch (EOFException exceptionES) {
    exceptionES.printStackTrace();
} finally {
    dataOutputStream.close();
    conex.close();
}
}
```

Client code (Android 2.2)

```
try {
client = new Socket(ip,port);
} catch (UnknownHostException e1) {
e1.printStackTrace();
} catch (IOException e1) {
e1.printStackTrace();
}

// We get the number of images that will be received.

try {
dataInputStream = new DataInputStream(client.getInputStream());
images = dataInputStream.readInt();
} catch (Exception e) {
e.printStackTrace();
}

do{
try {
    InputStream in = client.getInputStream();


            // Get stuck at this point!
    Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(in);


    if(bitmap==null)
        Log.e("Client", "bitmap is null!");

    File sd = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
    dir = new File(sd + "/Images/");

    File f = new File(dir, "image"+ dir.list().length + ".jpg");

    f.createNewFile();
    OutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(f);
    bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 90, os);
    os.close();

    numberOfImgRec++;
} catch (OptionalDataException e1) {
    e1.printStackTrace();
} catch (IOException e1) {
    e1.printStackTrace();
}

try {
    dataOutputStream= new DataOutputStream(client.getOutputStream());

    if(numberOfImgRec != images)
        dataOutputStream.writeUTF("OK");
    else
        dataOutputStream.writeUTF("END");
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();

}while(numberOfImgRec != images);
```

Comment: 1) You don't want to be getting the output and input streams from the sockets multiple times like that. Most socket implementations will create new streams every time you call those methods. 2) You probably want to send one image at a time, rather than all at once.

Comment: So what would you suggest?. Close the connection and reopen it again for each image?. Thanks for answering.

Comment: I saw that when I stop the server the bitmap is unlocked on client and get the image, but the other does not get it because the server is closed.